# delete selected row of multicolumn list box from excel vba

Tags: sql, vba

I have multicolumn and multi-select Listbox which loads records from access in excel userform. Trying to delete the stored employee numbers (string data type) by selecting rows from list box through the below method:

```
With frm.lb1
 For lrow =0 to .Listcount-1
  If .Selected(lrow) then strset=strset & .List(lrow, lcol) & ","
 Next lrow
End with

sqlQry="Select * from tablename where stringfield IN ('" & strset & "'" & ")"
rs.open sqlQry
```

for the sample, variable strset has selected list as `xyz125,xyz585,xyz471` and the sqlQry is

```
Select * from tablename where stringfield IN ('xyz125,xyz585,xyz471')
```

I don't have any way to have the above query  to execute the result as below

```
Select * from tablename where stringfield IN ('xyz125','xyz585','xyz471')
```

Comment: You need to concate single quote to each element of strset like strset= "'" & strset & .List(lrow, lcol) & "',"

Comment: strset= strset & "'" & .List(lrow, lcol) & "',"

Comment: Again not coming in query-----=  IN ( ' 'xyz123, ' 'xyz123, xyz129')

Comment: Do some debug and try

Comment: strset & "'" & .List(i,0) &"'" & "'," - working as expected